# transparent image on top of gradient background

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the background image to lay on top of the gradient background, do I have to create another div to do this?

```
#inner_bg {
    width: 846px;
    height: 646px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    background: url(../simg/inner_bg.gif) no-repeat 20px 140px;
    background: #031f34;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%, #03668f 40%, #05b7d1 70%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(9%,#031f34), color-stop(40%,#03668f), color-stop(70%,#05b7d1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#031f34', endColorstr='#05b7d1',GradientType=1 );
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need another element to work with (maybe a pseudo element like ::before), the backgrounds are replacing each other (when they are valid).

http://jsfiddle.net/fTpaz/2/

```
#inner_bg {
    width: 846px;
    height: 646px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%, #03668f 40%, #05b7d1 70%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(9%,#031f34), color-stop(40%,#03668f), color-stop(70%,#05b7d1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #031f34 9%,#03668f 40%,#05b7d1 70%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#031f34', endColorstr='#05b7d1',GradientType=1 );
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#inner_bg::before{
    content: ' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: red;
    opacity:0.5;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another divide. Position on top of the div with the gradient background. Add a z-index higher than that of the div with the gradient background.